# Custom Config file with subelements instead of attributes

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, web-config, app-config

I am working on making a custom section of my app.config and web.config to read a configuration in.  I'm following the code at http://consultingblogs.emc.com/pauloreichert/archive/2005/05/31/1514.aspx for my sample.  The problem is, my config file generates as follows:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="BizDays" type="Holidays.BizDaysSection, Holidays, Version=1.0.3883.29809, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</configSections>
<BizDays>
  <Holidays>
    <Holiday Name="New Years Day" Day="1" Month="1" />
    <Holiday Name="MLK Day" Month="1" DayOfWeek="1" WeekOfMonth="3" />
  </Holidays>
</BizDays>
```

What i am wanting is code like this:

```
<BizDays>
  <Holidays>
    <Holiday Name="New Years Day">
      <Day>1</Day>
      <Month>1 </Month>
    </Holiday>
    <Holiday Name="MLK Day">
      <Day>1</Day>
      <DayOfWeek>1</DayOfWeek>
      <WeekOfMonth>3</WeekOfMonth>
    </Holiday>
  </Holidays>
</BizDays>
```

None of the examples I can find online show how to do this.

Comment: Why? Seems terrible to me. Why not just keep subelements for actual complex types, not simple strings or ints?

Comment: Cause I asked if it could be done, not an opinion on the layout or the config itself. There could be other factors at work as to why I would like it this way.

Comment: Could you please post some code rather than making us read the article you linked to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reading the doc you have linked to, Name appears to be correctly specified as an XMLAttribute. Day, DayOfWeek, etc, should be XMLElements.

For example, creating an instance of the following class and serializing it would yield the result you are after:

```
public class Holiday
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name;
    [XmlElement]
    public int Day;
    [XmlElement]
    public int Month;
}
```

Since XmlElement is the default, it could be left off.